# pasting code yields multiple errors

Tags: indentation, python-3.4

I've copied this block straight out of my textbook and get many error messages, none of which have I been able to address. I have read and reread the section of my book and as far as I can tell it's all one block, so I'm confused as to why there would be unexpected indents. I'll post below my block the errors I'm struggling with.

```
import math

def archimedes (sides):

      innerangleB = 360.0 / sides
      halfangleA = innerangleB / 2

      onehalfsideS = math.sin(math.radians(halfangleA))

      sideS  =  onehalfsideS * 2

      polygonCircumference = sides * sideS

      polygonCircumference = sides * sideS
      pi = polygonCircumference/2

      return pi
```

...and here are the errors:

```
>>> import math
>>> 
>>> def archimedes (sides):
... 
  File "<stdin>", line 2

    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
>>>       innerangleB = 360.0 / sides
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    innerangleB = 360.0 / sides
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>       halfangleA = innerangleB / 2
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    halfangleA = innerangleB / 2
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>> 
>>>       onehalfsideS = math.sin(math.radians(halfangleA))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    onehalfsideS = math.sin(math.radians(halfangleA))
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>> 
>>>       sideS  =  onehalfsideS * 2
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    sideS  =  onehalfsideS * 2
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>> 
>>>       polygonCircumference = sides * sideS
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    polygonCircumference = sides * sideS
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>> 
>>>       polygonCircumference = sides * sideS
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    polygonCircumference = sides * sideS
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>       pi = polygonCircumference/2
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pi = polygonCircumference/2
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>    
...       return pi
```

Comment: This code works for me. Is all the indented code correctly indented with 4 spaces ?

Comment: Did you copy that code into a text editor or into the interactive shell? It seems you copied it into the shell. This won't work for complex code blocks. Copy it into a file, and run that file as `python filename.py`. If you _insist_ on copying ot into an interactive shell, you have to remove the blank lines.

Comment: You can also try pythonfiddle.com, I tested your code there, but unfortunately it can't seem to share it.

Comment: The empty lines terminate a block in the interpreter. Try writing to a file and running it with `python file.py`.

Comment: It is worth noting that encoding can disguise the problem if you are editing cross-platform. Pasting on a Pi (from code edited on Windows) I found the editor added blank lines - or more correctly displayed them differently in the editor to the way the terminal interprets them. Using Geany (simply because it was a default install) there is a "Convert and set to LF (Unix)" under Document > Set Line Encodings which handles the issue for me. There are also often fromdos or unix2dos commands.

Answer (score 5):

The code seems to be fine, but I can reproduce your problem when I copy that code into an interactive Python shell. The reason is that when there is a blank line, the Python shell will interpret that as the end of the current code block. Thus it tries to interpret the `def` line before there is any "body" to the function (thus the `expected an indented block` error), and then the different chunks of the indented body without a `def` (thus the multiple `unexpected indent` errors).

To fix it, you have two possibilities:

- Either, copy the code into a text file and execute that file with `python filename.py` or start an interactive Python shell and import the function with `from filename import archimedes`.
- Or remove all the blank lines in the body of the function and *then* paste it into an interactive shell.